# Permission denied when connecting via ssh (ipv6)

Tags: ssh, ipv6, rsa

I use a key to authenticate. When I connect using ipv4 it's working.

Using ipv6 I can not login (using password or not).

Do I need a seperate rsa-key to manage ipv6 ssh's?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Basic things first- have you confirmed that both IPv4 and v6 names / addresses point to the same place? And that sshd is listening for v6 connections? It's easy to get caught out!

Comment: Feeling dumb! :D `AddressFamily any` solved it. Thank you. Promising I gonna google a little more next time. :P :)

Comment: No problem, it's happened top me more than once! You could add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot to adjust `AddressFamily any` in sshd config file.

Edit: if you are managing several keys with in a `~/.ssh/config` file you need to add a seperate entry for the IPv6 connection.

Comment: It sounds like a DNS server would simplify the way you’re using your remote hosts.